# golang fiber defer os.Remove() not called

Tags: go

In my golang project I need to delete a file once it has been downloaded by user. I use defer but it is not called after download so the file is not deleted. The code is as follows:

```
func (h *Handler) Download(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
    filename := c.Query("filename")
    c.Attachment(filename)
    tempFile := filepath.Join(os.TempDir(), filename)

    //Open the file for reading
    file, err := os.Open(tempFile)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    //delete the file when everything is done, not working
    defer os.Remove(tempFile)
    
    //read the file
    b, err := ioutil.ReadAll(file)
    if err != nil {
        return er.Wrap(err)
    }

    //close the file explicitly after reading
    err = file.Close()
    if err != nil {
        return er.Wrap(err)
    }

    //also I tried to delete the file explicitly but keep getting error saying that the file is being used by another process
    //os.Remove(tempFile)
    //send the file to user
    return c.Send(b)
}
```

Any ideas how to fix it would be welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

mybe os.Remove return a error,eg. tempFile's path is error

use follow code to see the error

```
    defer func() {
        err := os.Remove(tempFile)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("%v\n", err)
        }
    }()
```